# Coupling Boundary Condition of one PDE with source term of another PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, multigrid, coupling

We have a system of equations, wherein the BC of one PDE is coupled with the source term of another PDE.

We have a regular 2D unit grid in x and y.

There are two PDEs to be solved

- The first PDE (elliptic diffusion problem) is defined only at $y = 1$, acting along the x-axis (i.e. it acts in the x-direction and only along the top of the cartesian grid). This x-axis is discretized with a fixed grid-spacing, generating a finite number of nodes. Let this set of nodes/co-ordinates be represented by $‘X’$.
- The second PDE is a time-varying diffusion problem. This is defined only along the y-axis, but for all x-nodes (i.e. for all $‘X’$), where the 1st PDE is being solved.

PDE1:

$$\nabla.(S \nabla a) = f(\omega,a)$$
BC1:   $\frac{\partial a}{\partial x} = 1$, at $x=1$ (Neumann)

BC2:   $a = 0$, at $x=0$ (Dirichelet)

PDE2:

$$\frac{\partial B}{\partial t} = \nabla.( \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & D  \end{array} \right) \nabla B)$$

BC1:   $B = 0$, at $y=0$ for all $'X'$, i.e. along the bottom face

BC2:   $\frac{\partial B}{\partial y} = g(\omega, a)$, at $y=1$ (Neumann)

$f$ and $g$ are linear functions in $\omega(x,y,t)$ and $a(x,y,t)$. $B$ is defined in the 2-D grid as $B(x,y,t)$.

**Importantly**, $$\omega=B_{y=1} \text{  for all  }  'X'$$

i.e., the BC2 of the 2nd PDE couples with the Implicit Source Term of the 1st PDE along the top face of the Cartesian mesh.

*How would one approach this problem in order to obtain a numerical solution via a FD/FV implementation?*